# parseFloat() from the middle of the string

Tags: javascript, parseint, parsefloat

I always have a "NaN" when wanted to "parseInt or parseFloat" from string like "Sometext 330"

```
Var a = "Sometext 330"
return parseFloat(a);
```

and it will return "NaN" but i need integer or float 330

Comment: Of course since the first character is not a number!

Comment: you will have to break the string down and check for the number you cannot parse that string becasue it contains text

Comment: If there are only two word, 1st text and 2nd numeric, then split it and take the numeric one only. By the way parseFloat is a javascript functionality you can not change it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could sanitize your string first so only digit's remain in the string before parsing the number.

> edit: now it's even safer as it will accept Number types without blowing up.

```js
var a = "Sometext 330"

function safeParseFloat(val) {
  return parseFloat(isNaN(val) ? val.replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '') : val)
}

function superSafeParseFloat(val) {
  if (isNaN(val)) {
    if ((val = val.match(/([0-9\.,]+\d)/g))) {
      val = val[0].replace(/[^\d\.]+/g, '')
    }
  }
  return parseFloat(val)
}

console.log(
  safeParseFloat(a),
  safeParseFloat(2000.69)
)

console.log(
  superSafeParseFloat('blah $2,000,000.69 AUD'),
  superSafeParseFloat('blah $8008 USD'),
  superSafeParseFloat('NotANumber'),
  superSafeParseFloat(8008.69),
  superSafeParseFloat('... something 500.5... test')
)
```

Comment: This won't work on a string like `"... something 500.5... test"` though.

Comment: @Annarfych good point. I updated the answer with a superSafe version. It's not internationally safe though

Answer (score 1):

You can also split the string too if your use case is always the same.

```js
var str = "test 900";
var split = str.split(' ');
// Loop through the split array
split.forEach(function(item){
  // If the split is not NaN
  if(!isNaN(item)){
    // Heres your number
    console.log(item);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

More elegant way :

```
Var a = "Sometext 330"
return parseFloat(a.match(/\d+$/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to parse floats/to float, you could use this regex:

```
    var numberStr = "fea$420.69atrg";
    return parseFloat(numberStr.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0]);
```

That'll return 420.69 here.